# Replace commas from string between < >

Tags: regex, string, coldfusion, replace

I have to replace comma from the substring which is between `<` and `>`.

I have tried the following,

```
<cfset a = '<span,style="text-decoration:,underline;">testing, process</span></i>' />
<cfset a = REReplace(a,"\<(.*?)\>"," ","ALL")>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perhaps try this regex:

```
REReplace(a,",(?=[^\<]*\>)"," ","ALL")
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH8qZ7)